# apache log parser doesn't work with the log files I have

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to planning to make a program that will clean a bunch of log files for me but I can't seem to get this simple counter to work with the log files I have. I'm still new to this type of programming but I suspect I might be using the wrong type of parser for the logs that I have. I thought they were standard apache logs but I must be mistaken. I've attached my code and a section of the log file in case that helps (IP addresses censored). Thanks

```
import apache_log_parser

parser = apache_log_parser.make_parser('%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s "%{User-agent}i"')   
count = 0

with open('sad-access_log-20180902.log') as in_f:
    for line in in_f:
        line = parser(line)
        count = count + 1

    print(count)
```

Contents of `sad-access_log-20180902.log`:

```
********- - [26/Aug/2018:03:50:04 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 255
******** - - [26/Aug/2018:03:50:03 +0100] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5836
********* - - [26/Aug/2018:03:50:05 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6812
************ - - [26/Aug/2018:03:50:11 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6812
```

Comment: Welcome, that does not look like `PHP`.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: Just curious if my answer helped you solve this in any way! If it did, I'd be happy if you marked the answer as accepted. If not, maybe we can help you further

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember this for your next question

- it is considered good practice on this site to include all relevant error messages you encounter
- you inlcuded code and input data - great! However, your code is not formatted correctly, which is bad, as Python is quite fickle with indentation

That said, let's get down to business.

- your logfiles contain no `UserAgent`-string. Parsing that will fail.
- what should `%>s` have parsed? The `>` character was not contained in your logfile
- the last field in your log is, as I mentioned, not a UA; instead, it seems more likely to be the size of the response, so I just used the format-string for that.

This code does what you expected:

```
import apache_log_parser

parser = apache_log_parser.make_parser('%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %B')
count = 0

with open('foo.log') as in_f:
    for line in in_f:
        line = parser(line)
        count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

Just in case you didn't read it, this is the link to [the documentation](https://github.com/rory/apache-log-parser) for `apache_log_parser`.